# Best practice with a possibility of a null interface object within class

Tags: c#, events, interface, class-design, cad

I've created a class that represent a component. This component has a width,height,x-Coordinate,y-Coordinate, etc. When I manipulate the width,height,x, and y, I want to keep the logic within the class. But there is an interface object within the Component Class that has similar values. This interface can be used to talk to different types of CAD software. The Shape interface can be null though.

So my question is what would be the best approach for this? In the example below, when I change "Y", should I check for null in the shape interface? Or maybe the Component Class has event handlers and the Shape Interface should register to them. So what would be best practice for designing this approach and what would give the best performance?

Appreciate it!

```
public class Component
{
    private double _y;

    public IShape Shape { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y
    {
        get => _y;

        set
        {
            _y = value;
            if (Shape != null) Shape.Y = value;
        }
    }

    public void Update_Shape()
    {
        //used to update the Shape Interface after it is assigned
    }

}

public interface IShape
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    double Width { get; set; }
    double Height { get; set; }
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE: To give more details, my interface will be able to talk to Microsoft Visio, and AutoCad. They are only meant to be used as a visual representation of the data, the are not in control of how many shapes, or where they are positioned. So in my application, the user can move, or change width/height within the application. If they have Visio open at the time, I want it to update Visio shapes as well. If it isn't open, then it doesn't matter(it will end up being updated later on). Same goes for AutoCad.

Comment: Triggering an event from Component class and Shape class responding to the would be a better approach then checking null.

Comment: Is `Shape` supposed to reflect the values in `Component`?

Comment: I see a few problems here. Firstly, it's possible for the component `Y` value to differ from the `Shape.Y` property, that seems to be impossible. I don't understand why you need the values in both places. Why doesn't `Component` just implement the `IShape` interface?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you don't have `Component` directly implement `IShape`? It seems to have all the necessary properties (you say it has "similar" properties, but in fact they are the exact same name and type).

Comment: Please clarify why you would have a separate property of type `IShape` that has identical properties to your class, and why would it be null if your class has values set?

Comment: Also, if `IShape` is null, then assigned after your object is constructed, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I updated the post to provide more information. It is possible for both the Ys can be different values. Component doesn't need to implement IShape. IShape will have a lot more methods that Component will not need.

Comment: This answer might seem a bit simplistic, but if the `IShape` instance is needed, I'd ensure that it can't be null. Perhaps pass it in the constructor. Something seems off with a class that has a dependency but it doesn't matter if it's null or not.

Comment: @ScottHannen But the Component Class doesn't depend on the IShape. It just needs the ability to change it if it does exist. As I said above, the IShape is there if the user is working in a CAD project, if he isn't, rather just working with data sheets, they can make changes to the component values without having CAD opened.

Comment: I understand. But it makes the code unclear if a method operates on something if it exists, but ignores it if it doesn't exist. Just like the comments show, someone wouldn't be able to tell what that `IShape` is for if it doesn't matter whether or not it's null. You mentioned raising events. That's a better approach. This class does what it does, and other classes do their own thing specific to the environment if and when it's applicable.

Comment: Cleaner code and performance is what I've been shooting for. I was going to go down the event approach as you and @ChetanRanpariya  mentioned, but Jerry provided an approach that looks clean and the performance would be better than Invoking an event. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in this situation depends on what your design goals are.

If you want to automatically update `IShape` and performance is critical then manually writing out your setters with a null check is going to give you both. Having an event that the IShape subscribes to causes you to have to invoke the event which is more expensive than checking null. And this has the benefit of keeping the mess inside the class as you only need to assign `myComponent.X = 20`;

Having an event has it's benefits. If you look up the Observer Pattern you can find lots of good reads on this. If you have more than one `IShape` that would subscribe to your `Component`, say from both Visio and AutoCad at the same time this would be the way to go.

Now in terms of performance, if you're update less than a few thousand components per second and you want cleaner code I would just call `Update_Shape()` when you want to synchronize the values. If you are assigning multiple values at the same time you can wrap them in an action that will automatically synchronize the values after it completes.

```
var c = new Component();
c.Shape = new Shape();

c.UpdateShapes(s => {
    s.Height = 100;
    s.Width = 100;
    s.X = 5;
});
```

```
public class Component
{
    public IShape Shape { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public void UpdateShapes(Action<Component> update)
    {
        update(this);
        SyncronizeShapes();
    }

    public void SyncronizeShapes()
    {
        if (Shape != null)
        {
            Shape.Name = Name;
            Shape.Width = Width;
            Shape.Height = Height;
            Shape.X = X;
            Shape.Y = Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your way of thinking. I didn't know that invoking was more taxing than checking for null. I was thinking about using your 1st recommendation, but then I figured I don't want the Shape to update every time I change it. Thanks for your example on using an "action". I haven't taken advantage of delegates yet, and this would be a great way to do this. Thanks!